# Calculus introduction

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I'm in **high school** who would like to learn about **calculus**.
I'm searching for **book/online resources** for those who are being introduced for the **first  time** into this subject.

Comment: Khan Academy (online) is good, and free. It also has information on all of the subjects leading up to it as well, so you can fill in any holes.

Comment: An unconventional suggestion: http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/calculus-for-the-ambitious

Comment: Different students studying calculus, even if they're all studying it for the first time, will want different kinds of books. That's because their level of mathematical ability will vary, as will their particular interests (e.g., theory vs. applications). To be able to make a recommendation, it would help to know these things about you. For a student of average ability in high school level math, I would recommend *E-Z Calculus* by Douglas Downing as a straightforward introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Stewart's Calculus is an indispensable resource for a young mathematician at your age.